# Locally storing entire webpage alongwith its javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to store webpages present in my iframes locally. Is there any way to save entire webpage locally, alongwith the scripts whose links are present in head tag?

I am able to save the webpage but not the scripts whose links are present in head tag of html. I am saving the webpage present inside the iframe using -

```
var framelist = document.getElementsByClassName("myFrame");
for (var i = 0; i < framelist.length; i++)
{
     APP_NAMESPACE.src_html_map[framelist[i].getAttribute("src")] = framelist[i].contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML;
}
```

I retrieve the locally stored webpage using -

```
for (var i = 0; i < framelist.length; i++)
{
     framelist[i].contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = APP_NAMESPACE.src_html_map[framelist[i].getAttribute("src")];
}
```

Now since the javascript files included in the webpages are not getting saved, I am not able to interact with the webpage.

Is there any way by which I can accomplish what I am trying to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: do you have control over the content in the iframe?

Comment: Yes I do have total control over the pages hosted inside the iframes.

Comment: I'm guessing that I am missing something. Why can't you load the src of the iframe into your browser, and choose file/save as/web page complete (or equivalent, depending on browser)?

*EDIT* - I think what I am missing is you want to do it programatically, right?

Comment: No that is not the purpose of what I am trying to do. I have multiple tabs, each tab hosts iframes, and some of the iframes in separate tabs host the same webpage. For those iframes (the one's which host the same webpage, but on different tabs), I don't want them to reload the webpage from scratch when I switch between tabs, so just trying to cache those webpages.